# How to render index.html from s3.getObject which fetched the website hosted on S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, routes, aws-api-gateway

I am having Lambda function which is invoked by AWS API Gateway, on that lambda function I need to serve the website in S3 bucket so that I can control access and routing on that website.

The following way which I used:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
//*/ get reference to S3 client 
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
  "Bucket": "mybucket",
  "Key": "index.html" 
    };


    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data){
       if(err) {
           callback(err, null);
       } 
       else {
           let response = {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "headers":
                {
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // to 
                //   "Content-Type": "text/html"
                },
                "body": JSON.stringify(data),
                "isBase64Encoded": false
            };
           callback(null, response);
        }
    });
};
```

Give the following output which is not what is needed.

```
{"AcceptRanges":"bytes","LastModified":"2020-03-28T08:10:04.000Z","ContentLength":661,"ETag":"\"08ea404c1973c83c8731a80bf5852d05\"","ContentType":"text/html","Metadata":{},"Body":{"type":"Buffer","data":[60,33,68,79,67,84,89,80,69,32,104,116,109,108,62,13,10,60,104,116,109,108,32,108,97,110,103,61,34,101,110,34,62,13,10,60,104,101,97,100,62,13,10,32,32,60,116,105,116,108,101,62,66,111,111,1...}
```

Comment: Is it a static website? If yes, you can use directly S3 to host your website.

Comment: No its dynamic Website. Where I can read the parameters passed and decide where to route in my S3 website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `getObject()` from the S3 API, per [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) the contents of your file are located in the Body property as buffer because it's a an asynchronous call. The execution of the code continues while the S3 code is stull running. You need to explicitly await for the call's promise to resolve.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
        "Bucket": "mybucket",
        "Key": "index.html" 
    };

    const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    callback(null, {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify(data),
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    });
};
```